# AutoCompleteStringCollection from 2 fields

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to get the value for the autoCompleteStringCollection from tow fields.? I have a table with fields Code and NameA, is it possible to get the autocomplete suggestions from both fields ? I am using c# in windows forms.

this is my code:

```
internal static System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection getAutoCompleteSiteNames(out System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();

                string query = @"Select distinct [NameA] from [tblItem]";
                SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
                namesCollection = new System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                SqlCeDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                    namesCollection.Add(dr["NameA"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return namesCollection;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "from two fields"?

Comment: There is never a reason to write code like `catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(); }`. Seriously, never. Take that out. Replace the whole try/finally construct with a `using` block wrapped around the connection object.

Comment: I have update my question. please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean something like

```
string query = @"Select distinct [NameA] from [tblItem] union
                 Select distinct [Code]  from [tblItem] ";
```

Comment: and how would i be able to add them in the collection ?                               while (dr.Read())
          namesCollection.Add(dr["NameA"].ToString());

Comment: You can use `dr[0]` instead of `dr["NameA"]`

Comment: Thank you it is working fine.

Comment: Select distinct [NameA] As [Autocompletevalue] from [tblItem] union
Select distinct [Code] As [Autocompletevalue] from [tblItem]. It is a little more clean and then you could use dr("Autocompletevalue").

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique occurrences of the autocomplete strings of two textboxes by using LINQ like this:

```
var allStrings = textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource
    .Cast<string>()
    .Union(
        textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource
        .Cast<string>()
    ).ToList();
```

---

**UPDATE**: You changed your question  completely, invalidation my previous answer.

I would split the task in two distinct tasks:

1. Read a table into a list of objects.
2. Get the autocomplete sources from the list of objects.

It makes it easier to process data, if you have a class representing the data, instead of dealing with the database directly. Create a class representing your data

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NameA { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    // ... other properties go here
}
```

Now you can read the items like this

```
public List<Item> GetAllItems()
{
    var items = new List<Item>();
    using (var con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new new SqlCeCommand("Select * from tblItem", con))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int idOrdinal = dr.GetOrdinal("ID");
        int nameAOrdinal = dr.GetOrdinal("NameA");
        int codeOrdinal = dr.GetOrdinal("Code");
        // other fields ...
        while (dr.Read()) {
            var item = new Item();
            item.ID = dr.GetInt32(idOrdinal);
            item.NameA = dr.GetString(nameAOrdinal);
            item.Code = dr.GetString(codeOrdinal);
           // other fields ...
            items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

It's even easier if you'd use a O/R-mapper like Entity Framework which automates this task.

Now you have a general means of returning items that you can use in all sorts of situations. Getting these autocomplete strings is just one of them.

```
 List<Item> items = GetAllItems();
 var autocompleteNames = items
     .Select(i => i.NameA)
     .Distinct()
     .ToArray();
 var autocompleteCodes = items
     .Select(i => i.Code)
     .Distinct()
     .ToArray();
 nameATextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(autocompleteNames);
 codeTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(autocompleteCodes);
```